Image '0' does not have a 'system:time_start' property - Google Earth Engine
I'm getting this error in code below while running the unique_dates.

FeatureCollection (Error) Error in map(ID=0): Image.date: Image '0'
does not have a 'system:time_start' property.

// Define the area of interest (AOI)
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([
    [74.0, 30.0],
    [75.0, 31.5]
]);

// Define start and end points for the river
var start_point = ee.Geometry.Point([74.53423023287748, 30.990726640340387]);
var end_point = ee.Geometry.Point([74.53429460589383, 30.995178030480833]);

// Define left and right shore coordinates
var shore_points = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(start_point, { 'id': 0 }),
    ee.Feature(end_point, { 'id': 1 })
]);

// Create lines between shore points to measure width
var create_cross_section = function(point1, point2) {
    return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.LineString([point1.coordinates(), point2.coordinates()]));
};

var shore_point_list = shore_points.toList(shore_points.size());
var cross_section = create_cross_section(start_point,end_point);

// Function to mask clouds using the quality band for Landsat 8 and 9
var mask_clouds = function(image) {
    var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
    var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5).eq(0);
    var cloud_shadow = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3).eq(0);
    return image.updateMask(cloud.and(cloud_shadow));
};

// Function to mask clouds using the quality band for Landsat 5 and 7
var mask_clouds_ls5_ls7 = function(image) {
    var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
    var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4).eq(0);
    var cloud_shadow = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 2).eq(0);
    return image.updateMask(cloud.and(cloud_shadow));
};

// Function to calculate NDWI
var calculate_ndwi = function(image) {
    var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI');
    return image.addBands(ndwi);
};

var landsat5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2020-12-30')
    .map(mask_clouds_ls5_ls7)
    .map(calculate_ndwi);
var landsat7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2020-12-30')
    .map(mask_clouds_ls5_ls7)
    .map(calculate_ndwi);
var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2020-12-30')
    .map(mask_clouds)
    .map(calculate_ndwi);
var landsat9 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2020-12-30')
    .map(mask_clouds)
    .map(calculate_ndwi);

// Function to measure width at cross-sections
var measure_width = function(image) {
    var get_width = function(feature) {
        var buffer = feature.geometry().buffer(500); // Adjust buffer as necessary
        var water_pixels = image.select('NDWI').gt(0).clip(buffer).reduceRegion({
            reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
            geometry: buffer,
            scale: 30
        }).get('NDWI');
        water_pixels = ee.Number(water_pixels).multiply(900).sqrt(); // Convert pixel count to distance (meters)
        return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), { 'width': water_pixels, 'date': image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd') });
    };
    return ee.FeatureCollection([get_width(cross_section)]);
};

// Combine Landsat collections
var combined_landsat = landsat5.merge(landsat7).merge(landsat8).merge(landsat9);
print(combined_landsat)
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: combined_landsat,
    description: 'combined_landsat_widths',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
var unique_dates = combined_landsat.aggregate_array('system:time_start')
                                    .map(function(date) { return ee.Date(date).format('YYYY-MM-dd'); })
                                    .distinct();

var mosaics = unique_dates.map(function(date) {
    date = ee.Date(date);
    var daily_images = combined_landsat.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'));
    var mosaic = daily_images.mosaic().set('date', date.format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
    return mosaic;
});

// Measure width for each mosaic
var widthsCollection = ee.ImageCollection(mosaics).map(function(image) {
    return measure_width(image).map(function(feature) {
        return feature.set('image_id', image.id());
    });
}).flatten();

// Print the widths collection to verify
print('Widths Collection:', widthsCollection);

// Export the widths data
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: widthsCollection,
    description: 'combined_landsat_widths',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

// Visualize NDWI and cross-sections for the single image
var firstImage = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection(mosaics).first());
var ndwi_vis = { min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['00FFFF', '0000FF'] };

Map.centerObject(aoi, 8);
Map.addLayer(firstImage.select('NDWI'), ndwi_vis, 'NDWI');
Map.addLayer(aoi, {}, 'AOI');
Map.addLayer(shore_points, { color: 'red' }, 'Shore Points');
Map.addLayer(cross_section, { color: 'blue' }, 'Cross Section');

But, combined_landsat has this time start property in properties section. How do I solve this error?



Do this post help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306962/metadata-property-systemtime-start-not-found-after-scaling-modis-npp-data?rq=1

The issue here is that the collection you are iterating over (mosaics) has lost the property system:time_start that was previously present in combined_landsat. The fix is easy, you just need to explicitly copy it from the original source:
var mosaics = unique_dates.map(function(date) {
    date = ee.Date(date);
    var daily_images = combined_landsat.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'));
    var mosaic = daily_images.mosaic()
      .set('date', date.format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
      .copyProperties(daily_images.first(),['system:time_start']);
    return mosaic;
});

