# Computed values outside of expected range (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, smoothing

I'm working with an NDVI (normalized difference vegetation index) time series. NDVI is expected to have a range [-1, 1]. My analysis, which applies a Whittaker Smoothing algorithm, is producing values in the range [0, 5000]. Did I introducing an error in the algorithm or is this a function of the data?

This is my code - https://code.earthengine.google.com/2572f72de1cc09004878e227096ed906

```js
var field = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-rubywilkinson11/assets/Duchy_1');
field = field.geometry();
Map.centerObject(field);
Map.addLayer(field, {color: 'red'}, 'field');

var startDate = '2010-01-01';
var endDate = '2020-12-31';

var images = modis.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate));
print(images);

var scaling = function(image){
  
    var scaled = image.select('NDVI').divide(10000);
    return scaled.copyProperties(image, ['system:index', 'system:time_start'])
    
}

var scaled_ndvi = images.map(scaling);

print(scaled_ndvi);

var nd = scaled_ndvi.first();


var mod_im = images.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index','2020_01_01')).first();
Map.addLayer(mod_im,{bands:['sur_refl_b02','sur_refl_b01','sur_refl_b03'], min:0,max:4000}, 'FCC');
Map.addLayer(nd,{min:0,max:1,palette:['white','Green']},'NDVI');

// helper function to convert qa bit image to flag
function extractBits(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
}
 
// function to get a Difference mattrix of specified order
// on the input matrix. takes matrix and order as parameters
function getDifferenceMatrix(inputMatrix, order){
    var rowCount = ee.Number(inputMatrix.length().get([0]));
    var left = inputMatrix.slice(0,0,rowCount.subtract(1));
    var right = inputMatrix.slice(0,1,rowCount);
    if (order > 1 ){
        return getDifferenceMatrix(left.subtract(right), order-1)}
    return left.subtract(right);
};
 
// unpacks an array image into images and bands
// takes an array image, list of image IDs and list of band names as arguments
function unpack(arrayImage, imageIds, bands){
     
    function iter(item, icoll){
         
        function innerIter(innerItem, innerList){
            return ee.List(innerList).add(ee.String(item).cat("_").cat(ee.String(innerItem)))}
         
        var temp = bands.iterate(innerIter, ee.List([]));
        return ee.ImageCollection(icoll)
            .merge(ee.ImageCollection(ee.Image(arrayImage).select(temp,bands).set("id",item)))}
 
    var imgcoll  = ee.ImageCollection(imageIds.iterate(iter, ee.ImageCollection([])));
    return imgcoll}
 
 
 
// Function to compute the inverse log ratio of a regression results to 
// transform back to percent units
function inverseLogRatio(image) {
  var bands = image.bandNames();
  var t = image.get("system:time_start");
  var ilrImage = ee.Image(100).divide(ee.Image(1).add(image.exp())).rename(bands);
  return ilrImage.set("system:time_start",t);
}
 
function whittakerSmoothing(imageCollection, isCompositional, lambda){
  // quick configs to set defaults
  if (isCompositional === undefined || isCompositional !==true) isCompositional = false;
  if (lambda === undefined ) lambda = 10;
 
  // procedure start  
  var ic = imageCollection.map(function(image){
     var t = image.get("system:time_start");
    return image.toFloat().set("system:time_start",t);
  });
 
  var dimension = ic.size();
  var identity_mat = ee.Array.identity(dimension);
  var difference_mat = getDifferenceMatrix(identity_mat,3);
  var difference_mat_transpose = difference_mat.transpose();
  var lamda_difference_mat = difference_mat_transpose.multiply(lambda);
  var res_mat = lamda_difference_mat.matrixMultiply(difference_mat);
  var hat_matrix = res_mat.add(identity_mat);
 
   
  // backing up original data
  var original = ic;
 
  // get original image properties
  var properties = ee.List(ic.iterate(function(image, list){
    return ee.List(list).add(image.toDictionary());
  },[]));
   
  var time = ee.List(ic.iterate(function(image, list){
    return ee.List(list).add(image.get("system:time_start"));
  },[]));
   
  // if data is compositional
  // calculate the logratio of an image between 0 and 100. First
  // clamps between delta and 100-delta, where delta is a small positive value.
  if (isCompositional){
    ic = ic.map(function(image){
      var t = image.get("system:time_start");
      var delta = 0.001;
      var bands = image.bandNames();
      image = image.clamp(delta,100-delta);
      image = (ee.Image.constant(100).subtract(image)).divide(image).log().rename(bands);
      return image.set("system:time_start",t);
    });
  }
 
  var arrayImage = original.toArray();
  var coeffimage = ee.Image(hat_matrix);
  var smoothImage = coeffimage.matrixSolve(arrayImage);
   
  var idlist = ee.List(ic.iterate(function(image, list){
    return ee.List(list).add(image.id());
  },[]));
  var bandlist = ee.Image(ic.first()).bandNames();
   
  var flatImage = smoothImage.arrayFlatten([idlist,bandlist]);
  var smoothCollection = ee.ImageCollection(unpack(flatImage, idlist, bandlist));
   
  if (isCompositional){
    smoothCollection = smoothCollection.map(inverseLogRatio);
  }
  // get new band names by adding suffix fitted
  var newBandNames = bandlist.map(function(band){return ee.String(band).cat("_fitted")});
  // rename the bands in smoothened images
  smoothCollection = smoothCollection.map(function(image){return ee.Image(image).rename(newBandNames)});
   
  // a really dumb way to loose the google earth engine generated ID so that the two
  // images can be combined for the chart
  var dumbimg = arrayImage.arrayFlatten([idlist,bandlist]);
  var dumbcoll = ee.ImageCollection(unpack(dumbimg,idlist, bandlist));
  var outCollection = dumbcoll.combine(smoothCollection);
   
  var outCollectionProp = outCollection.iterate(function(image,list){
      var t = image.get("system:time_start")
    return ee.List(list).add(image.set(properties.get(ee.List(list).size())));
  },[]);
 
  var outCollectionProp = outCollection.iterate(function(image,list){
    return ee.List(list).add(image.set("system:time_start",time.get(ee.List(list).size())));
  },[]);
 
 
  var residue_sq = smoothImage.subtract(arrayImage).pow(ee.Image(2)).divide(dimension);
  var rmse_array = residue_sq.arrayReduce(ee.Reducer.sum(),[0]).pow(ee.Image(1/2));
   
  var rmseImage = rmse_array.arrayFlatten([["rmse"],bandlist]);
   
  return [ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(outCollectionProp), rmseImage];
}
 
 
 
var ndvi =ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1").select('NDVI').filterDate("2010-01-01","2020-12-31");
// getting rid of masked pixels
ndvi = ndvi.map(function(img){return img.unmask(ndvi.mean())});
 
var ndvi =  whittakerSmoothing(ndvi)[0];

// add chart
print(ui.Chart.image.series(
  ndvi.select(['NDVI', 'NDVI_fitted']), field, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500)
    .setSeriesNames(['NDVI', 'NDVI_fitted'])
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Duchy 1  NVDI',
      series: {
    0: {lineWidth: 2, color: 'red', lineDashStyle: [2, 2]},
    1: {lineWidth: 5, color: 'blue', pointSize: 0}
  },
}));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Earth Engine Modis Data Scaling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301558/google-earth-engine-modis-data-scaling)

Answer (score 2):

Some floating point datasets are scaled to a large +/- integer to minimize the data type needed for storage. That is the case with MODIS/006/MOD13Q1. Generally, you can find scaling factors for bands under the "Bands" tab on Data Catalog pages ([for example](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MOD13Q1?hl=en#bands)). Also, some datasets include scaling factors in image properties.

I suspect that you need to apply your `scaling` function to the `ndvi` image collection. You apply the `scaling` function in what looks like exploratory code at the top of the script, but do not apply it in practice. The following may fix it (I can't test because an asset is not shared).

From:

```
var ndvi =ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1").select('NDVI').filterDate("2010-01-01","2020-12-31");
```

To:

```js
var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2020-12-31')
  .select('NDVI')
  .map(scaling);
```